# Node.js not responding ,Stuck at ---Bundling `index.js` [development, non-minified] ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 0.0% (0/1)

Tags: android, node.js, react-native

Starting working on app using react-native, Environment variable successfully setup, Running metro bundler port on:8081 successfully running.

ISSUE: stuck at

> Bundling `index.js`  [development, non-minified]  ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 
>   0.0% (0/1) emulator hangs showing loading from 10.0.2.2:8081

- OS: windows 8.1
- Node.js: 9.2.1
- npm:
- python: 2.7.14
- java: 1.8.151
- Android Studio:3.0.1
- Emulator:Nexus 5 API 23 ,marshmallow android 6.0(google APIs)

TRIED: Changing default port to 8088(did not work), already re-installed Node.js and updated Packages (did not work).